# ruby - determine version of core libraries offline

Tags: ruby

For non-core libraries, `gem list | grep rails` will show the version (e.g. `rails (5.1.4)`).

For core libraries, such as `openssl`,  without looking up the version of ruby then finding out on the internet, is there a way to locally determine what version?

`OpenSSL.methods` does not include an in-code way, there are no comments in the file (`~/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.rb` for me), the folder is not a git repository so I can't look at commit hashes... the only option surely can't be to checkout versions systematically and do a file by file comparison with the source code I have until I get an exact match?

Comment: `OpenSSL.constants` would've unearthed the solution

Comment: Note that openssl is not a core library, it is a standard library. Work is currently underway on gemifying the standard libraries. (Actually, in Rubinius, the standard libraries have been gemified for a long time, even the core library, and the compiler are installed as gems.) If openssl is already gemified (I haven't followed the process closely), then you should be able to find a gemspec and a version.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround solution, so not going to accept it:

Open interactive ruby documentation with `ri -i`

Type `OpenSSL` or whatever looking for, and hit enter... it tells you about it. Scroll down and you might find something like this:

```
Constants:

OPENSSL_FIPS:                                                                                                                                     [not documented]

OPENSSL_LIBRARY_VERSION:
  Version of OpenSSL the ruby OpenSSL extension is running with

OPENSSL_VERSION:
  Version of OpenSSL the ruby OpenSSL extension was built with

OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER:
  Version number of OpenSSL the ruby OpenSSL extension was built with (base
  16)

VERSION:
  OpenSSL ruby extension version
```

Thus in a ruby console you can do this:

```
irb> require 'openssl'
=> true
irb> OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION
=> "OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017"
```

So the generalised solution, is read the interactive docs, looking for a conveniently named constant, then access said constant from console.